# Error in if (is.na(sra_acc$run[i])) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, sratoolkit

I am trying to write a code for importing sra files as fastq files in Rstudio (for obtaining and aligning RNA-seq reads from public repositories). I keep getting "Error in if (is.na(sra_acc$run[i])) { : argument is of length zero" right after I run this code. Any suggestions on what might be going wrong? My code is as follows:

```
library(SRAdb)
sqlfile <-'SRAmetadb.sqlite'
if(!file.exists('SRAmetadb.sqlite')) sqlfile <<- getSRAdbFile()
sra_con <- dbConnect(SQLite(),sqlfile)
sraInf <- getSRAinfo("SRP045534",sra_con, sraType="sra")

Error in if (is.na(sra_acc$run[i])) { : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: Have you confirmed whether `file.exists('SRAmetadb.sqlite')` is TRUE or FALSE? Or generally, what the value of any of your variables is? I am not familiar with this library but having `sqlfile` be a string that is overwritten by the return value of `getSRAdbFile()` (don't know what that is) seems like it might cause an issue. Also, are you intending to use the superassignment operator (`<<-`)? I believe that you are using it in a non-standard way: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-April/275905.html

Answer (score 2):

After checking with `file.exists()`, I would suggest you try the same command with another SRA run. It may happen that some runs are not accessible for reasons I do not know. I always have problems in accessing sra formatted files and use a workaround to download fastq.

Here is my not official workaround:

```
runlist<-sraConvert("SRP045534",sra_con=sra_con)
runlist[1:2,]

study submission    sample experiment        run
1 SRP045534  SRA179382 SRS685546  SRX681992 SRR1552451
2 SRP045534  SRA179382 SRS685544  SRX681990 SRR1552449

for (dloadrun in runlist$run) 
{
    getSRAfile(dloadrun,sra_con=sra_con,fileType="fastq")
}
```

This should iteratively download all the runs associated to the project you are studying.
It is possible that you can do the same with sra type file, but I have never been able to use them with sraDB, and never investigated the issue.

Comment: I am also having this issue- my SQL file comes back as TRUE when I use file.exists but then in Fabio's workaround, the table comes out blank. Same error as you if I use getSRAfile.